# Can Apache Spark use TCP listener as input?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Can Apache Spark use TCP listener as input?  If yes, maybe someone has examples of java code, that do the operation.

I try to find examples about this, but all tutorials show how to define input connection to the data server via TCP and not using a TCP listener that waits for incoming data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark does not have an in-built TCP server to wait for producers and buffer data. Spark works on a polling mechanism for TCP, Kafka etc via its API libraries.. To consume incoming TCP data you need to have an external TCP server which Spark can connect to as explained by Shaido in example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use Spark to listen to a TCP port and process any incomming data. What you are looking for is [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html).

There is a small guide that listens to a TCP source in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example) and on [github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java). For convenience:

```
import org.apache.spark.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import scala.Tuple2;

// Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));

// Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);

// Split each line into words
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).iterator());

// Count each word in each batch
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

// Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
wordCounts.print();

jssc.start();              // Start the computation
jssc.awaitTermination();   // Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I already test this code from the user guide. This code connects to the existing TCP server, and receive the data from it. I need the TCP listener, that will wait for data, that send agent from another server.

Comment: @Vakhtang: Hi, this code will listen to a specified port for any data that is sent to the TCP socket. It will wait for any data that is sent so I think it's what you want? If not, can you be a bit more specific of what the difference is?

Comment: Hi, I test this code again... This code tries to connect, to existing TCP socket.. even in the code you can see comment: "Create a DStream **that will connect** to hostname: port, like localhost:9999". And if you haven't the server in this port you'll receive the error: `Error connecting to localhost:9999: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` If I understudy right there is no out of the box solution.